# how to change the FixedSingle of another program in c#

Tags: c#

I want to use a command to change the value of FormBorderStyle to the Sizable value of another program like the SetWindowPos command to change the window size or SetWindowText to change the title name in c#, but I haven't found it yet so I hope everyone Can you suggest that command so I can find and refer to it?

Comment: What's the context here? What is FixedSingle?

Comment: @JonSkeet `Form.FormBorderStyle` in WinForms. So the OP is asking how to change the border-style of arbitrary Win32 top-level application windows.

Comment: are you talking about the windows border style? the windows API lists a lot of messages and functions that can be used to modify current windows. also do not assume that the border styles defined in the .net-runtime are applicable to non-managed executables

Comment: @Dai: Right. I *suspect* that may be the case, but the question should be *much* clearer.

Comment: Because that program does not allow me to customize the size, I want to set it to Sizable or FixedSingle so I can drag it as big and small as I want.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry for asking a unclear question, but the problem is that i don't know of any APIs that support the formborderstyle of an external program

Comment: Ask yourself why a program would allow another process to modify it in that way (or any other way), or why the O/S would allow that. Sounds like a hacker's dream. That might be why you can't find any information about it!

Comment: You'd have to pinvoke SetWindowLongPtr() to modify the GWL_STYLE and SetWindowPos() with SWP_FRAMECHANGED to refresh the frame.  The odds that this program can correctly keep the window updated when its size changed are not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, using GetWindowLongPtr and SetWindowLongPtr :D

```
  private const uint GWL_STYLE = 0xFFFFFFF0;
    private const uint WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000;
    private const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
            private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, uint nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
    
            [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")]
            private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(IntPtr hWnd, uint nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
    
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern UInt32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, uint nIndex);
    
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    public static IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, uint nIndex, uint dwNewLong)
            {
                if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                {
                    return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new IntPtr(SetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong));
                }
            }
    
            public static IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, uint nIndex)
            {
                if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
                {
                    return GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, nIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new IntPtr(GetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex));
                }
            }
```

change properties

```
uint GSTYLE= (uint)GetWindowLongPtr(Hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(Hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GSTYLE| WS_SIZEBOX);
```

recovery

```
uint GSTYLE= (uint)GetWindowLongPtr(Hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(Hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GSTYLE& ~(WS_SIZEBOX));
```